# Need additional log

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I have a Python Flask application that is only showing 7 out of 10 pages on my remote server. The other pages are showing

> An unexpected error has occurred

I have checked the wsgi status-No error, error.log - no errors and wsgi status.

Is there anywhere else that I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try running your server while activating werkzeug debugger.

You can do it like that:

Option 1:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Option 2:

```
app.config['DEBUG']=True
```

Comment: thank you for responding.. the only thing that came up from using option 2 is
[13/Mar/2018:19:38:33 -0500] "GET /static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 62935 "http://87.155.228.48/dash/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
~

Comment: Now try navigating to the problematic pages and see what the debugger gives you, you'll see where your server corrupted, what exception was thrown